# Can I run my heroku app in Test/Development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rspec

I was trying to run my test cases on heroku.
Fund many blogs/answers telling how to run staging/custom environment on heroku.But whenever I run `heroku run rspec spec/` it returns `you are running production environment`(not exact error).

So my qustion is not how to run staging/custom evironment on heroku but when I login into heroku rails console, I should be able to see 
`Rails.env #=> test`
Or staging or whatever.
Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Why are you trying to run rspec on Heroku?  Check out CircleCI.com or something similar.

Comment: I want to run Feature specs also, which would be running at sauce labs for cross browser/os compatibility. Will run heroku as host environment for Sauce. Current requirement is to run test cases on a freezed environment.

Comment: CircleCI can do that https://circleci.com/docs/browser-testing-with-sauce-labs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In heroku dashboard, you should just set `RAILS_ENV` and `RACK_ENV` to `test`.

You can do that here:
[image]

After setting these variables, I was able to start the console in test environment.

[image]

Comment: This will still fail for feature specs requiring :firefox binary.

Comment: can you set up a small example project on `github` to reproduce your error?